# Exportar de Excel hacia SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

estoy intentando Exportar información de Excel hacia SQL Server a través de VBA, pero no lo quiero hacer línea por línea porque son más de 10mil registros y tarda entre 20 a 25 minutos. 
Lo que intento hacer es pasar el contenido de un archivo de un solo "golpe". El código que tengo actualmente me marca error en la línea de código **cnn.Execute nSQL & nJOIN**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este error, o que tenga una mejor manera de hacer esto desde VBA?

Este es el código actual que tengo:

```
Sub ExportarDatosDeExcel_A_SQLServer()
Dim strFileName  As String, nSQL As String, nJOIN As String
Dim cnn As Object
Dim wbkOpen As Workbook
Dim objfl As Variant
Dim rngName As Range

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Carlos.cortinas\Desktop\PROYECTOS\XXXXXX\Pruebas V03.1.xlsm"

Set wbkOpen = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("RESULTADO").Select

Set rngName = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown))

strFileName = wbkOpen.FullName

Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
                "Data Source=184.168.194.70;" & _
                "Initial Catalog= XXXXXX;" & _
                "User ID=XXXXXX;" & _
                 "Password=XXXXXX;"

nSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.Consolidado"
nJOIN = " SELECT * from " & "[RESULTADO" & rngName.Address(True, True) & "]"
cnn.Execute nSQL & nJOIN

MsgBox "Carga exitosa"
wbkOpen.Close
Set wbkOpen = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que error marca? y el codigo ponelo como texto, si no, quien te quiera ayudar tiene que copiar todo a mano en lugar de copiar y pegar del tuyo

Comment: ¿Cual es el valor de `rngName`?

Answer (score 2):

Existen varias maneras de importar datos de Excel hacia SQL Server, y con esa cantidad de registros, deberían de tardar muy pero que muy pocos segundos.

No expones, si lo que tienes que hacer es algo repetitivo o es una importación de una vez, si bien, da igual porque de todas las maneras se puede hacer repetitivo, pero unas son más simples que otras.

Voy a ponerte por ejemplo utilizando una query y OpenRowSet

Lo primero mirar si tienes el proveedor Microsoft.Ace.OleDb.12.0 en la maquina del SQL Server. Sino toca descargarlo e instalarlo

```
exec sys.sp_enum_oledb_providers
```

Luego preparar el servidor para realizar consultas remotas

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad hoc dis', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop 
N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop 
N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
```

Ahora tocaría comprobar que funciona con una consulta tal que:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
,'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\Carlos.cortinas\Desktop\PROYECTOS\XXXXXX\Pruebas V03.1.xlsm;HDR=YES'
,[NombreHoja$])
```

Hay que definir el nombre de la hoja del libro que vamos a leer.

Si la query te retorna datos, y no requieren de ningún procesamiento.

```
Insert into TuTabla (col1,col2,...)
 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
    ,'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\Carlos.cortinas\Desktop\PROYECTOS\XXXXXX\Pruebas V03.1.xlsm;HDR=YES'
    ,[NombreHoja$])
```

[Excel con OpenRowSet](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/05/09/importar-desde-excel-con-openrowset/)

También puedes utilizar la importación con el Management Studio y SSIS.
Muy fácil.

[Importar con Management Studio](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/09/02/importar-desde-excel-a-sql-server-facil-y-rapido/)